# How to calculate sizes on css based on other elements?

Tags: html, css, dom, layout

I would like to know if you can use `calc()` or something else to calculate the size of an element based on another DOM element size.

Comment: No. Not currently with CSS. It requires JS to relate the properties of element which are not nested.

Comment: what you want to do by calculating the size? BTW, css has no functions concept to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.offset`

something like this

```
var width = document.getElementById('element').offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('element').offsetheight;
```

requires js of course.

Comment: Yeah, JavaScript is the logical option to do this. I was wondering if there was any sort of css selector that allowed one to do that.